# High performance fullscreen visualization of image sequence

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, dynamic, visualization, system-performance

What is the fastest way you can come up with to display an image sequence in fullscreen where each image in the sequence must be shown? Here is my attempt. Let's create a 1920x1080 image as this is a rather common screen resolution.

```
data = Import["ExampleData/ozonemap.hdf", {"Datasets", "TOTAL_OZONE"}];
img = Rasterize@ListDensityPlot[
  Reverse[data],
  AspectRatio -> 9/16,
  ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors",
  DataRange -> {{-180, 180}, {-90, 90}},
  Frame -> None,
  ImageSize -> {1440, 810},
  ImageMargins -> 0,
  ImagePadding -> 0,
  PlotRangePadding -> None
];
```

You can verify the image size by evaluating `ImageDimensions[img]`. Now let's create a sequence of images using `img`.

```
imglist = Table[ImageEffect[img, {"Solarization", k}], {k, 1, 0, -1/300}];
```

The following code opens a new notebook and displays the image sequence.

```
CreateDocument[
 Animate[
  If[k == Length[imglist], stopTime = AbsoluteTime[]];
  Graphics[
   Dynamic[imglist[[k]]],
   Frame -> None,
   ImageSize -> 1440,
   ImageMargins -> 0,
   ImagePadding -> 0,
   PlotRangePadding -> None
  ],
  {{k, 1, ""}, 1, Length[imglist], 1, ControlType -> Animator, AppearanceElements -> {}},
  AnimationRepetitions -> 1,
  DisplayAllSteps -> True,
  AppearanceElements -> {},
  RefreshRate -> 30,
  FrameMargins -> None,
  ImageMargins -> 0,
  Paneled -> False,
  Deployed -> True,
  Initialization :> {startTime = AbsoluteTime[];}
 ],
 CellMargins -> 0,
 ShowCellBracket -> False,
 WindowSize -> Full,
 Editable -> False,
 Selectable -> False,
 WindowMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 WindowElements -> {},
 WindowToolbars -> {}
]
```

We can evaluate the framerate via `fps = Length[imglist]/(stopTime - startTime)`. The result I am getting is 11.12 fps which is not bad but not great either. Can you do better?

BTW, evaluating `SetSystemOptions["DynamicUpdateInterval" -> 0.01]` does not improve the performance in my case. Interestingly, removing `Dynamic` results in a worse performance on my system of 9 fps.

Also, do you know how to get rid of the grey bar still visible in `Animate` despite my attempts to make it disappear?

**Update:** Using `Dynamic` instead of `Animate` yields a higher frame rate but I am not sure whether each image of the sequence is shown or whether frame drops occur. Here is the code yielding a frame rate of 26 fps to 35 fps which is quite good. Strangely, it varies quite a bit.

```
CreateDocument[
 DynamicModule[
  {k},
  k = 0;
  startTime = AbsoluteTime[];
  Dynamic[
   If[k < Length[imglist], k++, stopTime = AbsoluteTime[]];
   Refresh[
    Graphics[
     Dynamic[imglist[[k]]],
     Frame -> None,
     ImageSize -> 1440,
     ImageMargins -> 0,
     ImagePadding -> 0,
     PlotRangePadding -> None
    ]
   ],
   UpdateInterval -> 0.01
  ]
 ],
 CellMargins -> 0,
 ShowCellBracket -> False,
 WindowSize -> Full,
 Editable -> False,
 Selectable -> False,
 WindowMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 WindowElements -> {},
 WindowToolbars -> {}
]
```

Comment: One thing you can do is to Export the image list as a mp4 (or other video format).

Comment: That is true but I would like to know what is the fastest way to display the image sequence in real time as well as how to get rid of the grey bar :)

Comment: One possibility is streaming the images through LibraryLink to the native world, then using native tools like OpenGL, DirectX, etc. to display them.

Comment: Good point. I am primarily interested though in how fast it can be made using Mathematica (Wolfram language) only.